# Can someone explain me this proof (complex analysis)?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, maximum-principle

I need to prove that gives a function $f\in H(\Bbb C)$ such that $f(z)=f(z+i)=f(z+1) \forall z\in\Bbb C$, then $f$ is costant.
The proof is the following:

Be $\gamma = [0, 1] + [1, 1 + i] + [1 + i, i] + [i, 0]$ and $z \in\mathbb C$ then $z$ can be written as $z=a+s+ti$ with $s,t \in\mathbb Z, a \in Int\gamma$.
For assumption we have:
$f (z) = f (a + s + ti) = f (a + s + (t − 1)i) = \dots = f (a + s) = f (a)$. This results in the maximum principle
$|f(z)| = |f(a)| \le ||f||\gamma = c$
Accordingly, $f$ is limited and therefore constant according to Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Do you know/understand Liouville's theorem ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The proof uses these steps:

- For every $z\in\Bbb C$, there is some $a\in\operatorname{Int}\gamma$ such that $f(z)=f(a)$.
- Since $\operatorname{Int}\gamma$ is compact, the restriction of $f$ to it is bounded.
- It follows from the previous steps that $f$ is bounded.
- Since it is bounded, it is constant, by Liouville's theorem.